# How can I use GPIO pins on an esp12e UART?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu, shields, uart

I've bought an esp12e UART that unfortunately had some issues, but I was able to fix them.
[image]

This is how I connected it to the arduino. With this setup, I was able to host a simple web server and it worked, the code uploaded and everything worked fine as it should. However, then I tried to make it light the led up by declaring it as on pin 13, but it didn't work, so I don't really know how should I declare my pins for the code to work as it should. By the way, the board is selected as nodemcu 1.0 (esp-12e module) in the arduino IDE if that helps. Thank you in advance

Comment: please remove the esp12e UART and try again ... the arduino uno probably already has an LED on pin 13

Comment: the shields headers are Uno headers, not esp8266 headers

Comment: @jsotola I can't remove the esp12e UART, I want to use it with the arduino.

Comment: @Juraj I understand, so how can I use the Uno headers when programming the esp8266?

Comment: it is a WiFi shield. put a firmware into esp8266 and use in Uno a WiFi library for that firmware

Comment: @Juraj thanks for the help, I've tried that way, but it didn't work, i guess i gotta try more methods for it to make it work if it's the only way.

Comment: you can write two sketch and code the communication but working with WiFi library is simpler.  https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT/blob/master/README.md